# MS Word: Mentioning image numbers in a text causes wrong number increasing for image numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, images

In Microsoft Office Word 2016, I assign an image under a paragraph, then gave an image with image number. I wanted to mention the image as "Image 1", but Word knows that Image 1 is used, so Image 2 will need to be used before (But Word can't understand that this was just a mention in text not a real image available), so Word makes Image 1 is should be Image 2 because Image 1 is used. How can we fix this image number ordering?

Example:

```
... , and some good flowers are can be seen on Image 1 below.

*Imagine there is an image on here*

Image 2: A flower picture with a vase
```

Actually, it has to be Image 1, but Word knows Image 1 is used before.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Please don't put the answer as part of your question as people don,t know it's been resolved

Comment: I found the solution with Word Cross-Reference.